# Facebook graph API returning only published photos but not videos (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I have successfully obtained publish_actions from facebook and now when I post a photo or video it gives me an object id in response. But whenever I try to retrieve a public video that was posted to a timeline through the app, it just gives me error code: 100 and no such error is seen when retrieving photos. Both are published to according endpoints /user/photos and /user/videos. The same user access token is used to retrieve both, so what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that I needed a user_videos permission. I still don't get why because the documentation clearly states that I can obtain any public video.